# nested route in react js dose not work correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

this is an App component

```
...
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route  path = '/shop' component = {Shop}  />  
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
...
```

and this is an Shop component

```
...
const {url , path} = useRouteMatch()
    return (
        <>
            <Route path = {`${path}/two`}  >
            <Two/> 
            </Route>
        <div>   
          <Link to = {`${url}/two`}>nested</Link>
        </div>
        </>
...
```

the problem is when I use exact like below

```
<Route exact path = '/shop' component = {Shop}  />
```

the URL will change correctly but the `<Two/>` component will not render
so anyone has an Idea?

Comment: You need to wrap the Shop -> Route component in  <Switch> component

Comment: I had tried this  too but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are missing wrap the `Route` component inside `Switch` component:

**Shop component**

```
 <>
    <Switch>
     <Route path = {`${path}/two`}  >
         <Two/> 
     </Route>
    </Switch>
    <div>   
       <Link to = {`${url}/two`}>nested</Link>
    </div>
 </>
```